# how to split column when meet special character

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, split

I need to split the data in single column to multi column.
I have the data like this

```
ID       NAME                COMMENT
1        TEST      Reg: 0001 Inv: B0001 Cus: A0001 Br: F0001
2        TEST1     Reg: 0002 Inv: B0002 Cus: A0002 Br: F0002
3        TEST2     Reg: 0003 Inv: B0003 Cus: A0003 Br: F0003
4        TEST3     Reg: 0004 Inv: B0004 Cus: A0004 Br: F0004
5        TEST4     Reg: 0005 Inv: B0005 Cus: A0005 Br: F0005
5        TEST4     Reg: 00010 Inv: B00010 Cus: A00010 Br: F00010
```

And I need to split the data in table comment, so it become like this:

```
REG        INV      BR 
0001      B0001    F0001
0002      B0002    F0002
0003      B0003    F0003
0004      B0004    F0004
0005      B0005    F0005
00010      B00010    F00010
```

Any suggestions how to do this?

My Code .

```
;WITH Split_Names (Comment)
    AS
    -- Define the CTE query.
    (
        SELECT 
        CONVERT(XML,'<COMMENTS><Comment>'  
        + REPLACE(
     REPLACe(
     REPLACE(
     REPLACE(
    REPLACE(
     REPLACE(Comment,'Reg:',''),'Inv:',','),'Cus:',','),'Br:',','),' ' ,'')
        ,',', '</Comment><Comment>') + '</Comment></COMMENTS>') AS xmlComments
         FROM GenTransaction
    )
    -- Define the outer query referencing the CTE name.
     SELECT      
     Comment.value('/COMMENTS[1]/Comment[1]','varchar(100)') AS Reg,    
     Comment.value('/COMMENTS[1]/Comment[2]','varchar(100)') AS Inv,
     Comment.value('/COMMENTS[1]/Comment[3]','varchar(100)') AS Cus,
     Comment.value('/COMMENTS[1]/Comment[4]','varchar(100)') AS Br

     FROM Split_Names
```

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: My suggestion is to import your data into the columns you actually want.  Inside SQL Server is not the best placr to be doing a cleanup like this.

Comment: thanks, version 10.50.1617.0

Comment: Have you looked at using SUBSTRING AND CHARINDEX functions?

Comment: @SQLAndOtherStuffGuy i tried, but because i get different length of data, so it not very useful for me

Comment: Is it always Reg, Inv, Cus and Br, or can there be other "columns" as well?

Comment: @ZoharPeled yup , can be other "column" the important is nid to split the data

Comment: Read [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad), where you will see a lot of reasons why the answer to this question is  **Absolutely yes!**

Comment: And also, read Aaron Bertrand's [Split strings the right way – or the next best way](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following solution should work

[ 1 ] No matter which order is used for items of `Comment` column (`Reg, Inv, Cus Br` or `Cus, Br, Reg, Inv` or something else) and also

[ 2 ] Some items of `Comment` column could be missing (ex. TEST4 / Cus is missing)

[ 3 ] If `Comment` contains XML reserved chars then instead of `REPLACE(t1.Comment,` should be used`REPLACE((SELECT t1.Comment AS '*' FOR XML PATH('')),`

```
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE (
    ID      INT NOT NULL,
    Name    NVARCHAR(50),
    Comment NVARCHAR(500)
);
INSERT  @Table1 (ID, Name, Comment)
VALUES 
(1, 'TEST ', 'Reg: 0001 Inv: B0001 Cus: A0001 Br: F0001'),
(2, 'TEST1', 'Reg: 0002 Inv: B0002 Cus: A0002 Br: F0002'),
(3, 'TEST2', 'Reg: 0003 Inv: B0003 Cus: A0003 Br: F0003'),
(4, 'TEST3', 'Reg: Coco&Jambo Inv: B0004 Cus: A0004 Br: F0004'), -- & = reserved XML char
(5, 'TEST4', 'Reg: 0005 Inv: B0005 Br: F0005'), -- Cus is missing
(5, 'TEST4', 'Cus: 3333 Br: 4444 Reg: 1111 Inv: 22222'); -- Different order

;WITH BaseQuery AS 
(
    SELECT  t1.ID, t1.Name, 
                CONVERT(XML, '<root><item>' 
                + REPLACE(
                    REPLACE(
                        REPLACE(
                            REPLACE((SELECT t1.Comment AS '*' FOR XML PATH('')), 
                            'Reg:', 
                            '</item><item type="Reg">'), 
                        'Inv:', 
                        '</item><item type="Inv">'), 
                    'Cus:', 
                    '</item><item type="Cus">'), 
                'Br:', 
                '</item><item type="Br">') + '</item></root>') CommentAsXml
    FROM    @Table1 t1
)
SELECT  bq.ID, bq.Name, 
        Reg = LTRIM(RTRIM(bq.CommentAsXml.value('(root/item[@type="Reg"])[1]', 'VARCHAR(11)'))),
        Inv = LTRIM(RTRIM(bq.CommentAsXml.value('(root/item[@type="Inv"])[1]', 'VARCHAR(11)'))),
        Cus = LTRIM(RTRIM(bq.CommentAsXml.value('(root/item[@type="Cus"])[1]', 'VARCHAR(11)'))),
        Br  = LTRIM(RTRIM(bq.CommentAsXml.value('(root/item[@type="Br"])[1]', 'VARCHAR(11)')))
FROM    BaseQuery bq
```

Results:

[image]

[Demo here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=294ef45760734ee33cd74b3947d5b662)

Comment: Msg 9411, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
XML parsing: line 1, character 45, semicolon expected
Msg 9421, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
XML parsing: line 1, character 44, illegal name character

Comment: line 1 which is from "------;WITH BaseQuery AS ----"

Comment: @tang: copy & paste my example into new query window in SQL Server Management Studio. You have to get the same results as those from inserted picture.

Comment: @tang: Have you succeed to copy & paste & run successfully this solution ?

Comment: yes success, but i cant apply in my code, it gt error

Comment: @tang: Check maximum length used for VARCHAR (11 in my solution) it it fits on your scenario.

Comment: ok, so is it possible is use the data split from the column as id to join with other table variable?

Comment: this is  my another question, hope can get some suggestion 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45450874/how-to-join-cte-query-with-another-table-in-sql-server-2008

Comment: @tang: I'm going to take a look in few minutes.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Basically what I am doing is replacing Reg:Inv: etc with commas, stripping out spaces and using XML to derive the columns values.

[image]

So I'm reffering to @Bogdan Sahlean solution below for handling XMl special characters in the comment field. Try this;

```
      ;WITH Split_Names (COMMENT)
        AS
        -- Define the CTE query.
        (
            SELECT 
            CONVERT(XML,'<COMMENTS><COMMENT>'  
    + 
    REPLACE(
    REPLACe(
    REPLACE(
    REPLACE(
    REPLACE(
    REPLACE(
    (SELECT Comment AS '*' FOR XML PATH('')) 
    ,'Reg:',''),'Inv:',','),'Cus:',','),'Br:',','),' ' ,'')
    ,',', '</COMMENT><COMMENT>') + '</COMMENT></COMMENTS>') AS xmlname
             FROM 


 GenTransaction
        )
        -- Define the outer query referencing the CTE name.
         SELECT      
         COMMENT.value('/COMMENTS[1]/COMMENT[1]','varchar(100)') AS Reg,    
         COMMENT.value('/COMMENTS[1]/COMMENT[2]','varchar(100)') AS Inv,
         COMMENT.value('/COMMENTS[1]/COMMENT[3]','varchar(100)') AS Cus,
         COMMENT.value('/COMMENTS[1]/COMMENT[4]','varchar(100)') AS Br

         FROM Split_Names
```

Comment: sorry, i am not familiar in CTE what should i put in xmlname?

Comment: Replace YOURTABLENAME with he name of the table you are working with.

Comment: "----Msg 9421, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
XML parsing: line 1, character 44, illegal name character-----" i get this error

Comment: Odd. I've run this SQL against your sample data and got the results in my screen shot.

Comment: Actually my Column name is  "Comment" i replace all the "COMMENT" word in your code, but it still get the same error

Comment: I suspect you haven't copied the code correctly. The error you are getting would suggest that one of the XML Nodes has a name with an illegal character in it. Can you show a screen shot of your entire SQL?

Comment: i jus copy your code, change the table field and run, the rest i dosen't edit anything.

Comment: Ok then, I suspect some of the data in your comment fields has some XML type values or reserved characters, without seeing a more comprehensive set of values from the comment column would be difficult to see what's causing this.

Comment: Looks good. Then I suspect as above that there is an issue with the data itself.

Comment: is it i nid to include all my column name into CTE query?

Comment: No, it's specifically related to the "Comment" Column as it's using xml on that column to derive values. Have a look at your data in Comment column. Is there anything that looks like it has characters like any of these. '&', '<', '>'

Comment: Cool. I've updated the solution to handle this. Thanks to @Bogdan Sahlean