# How to join CTE query with another table in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression

I have created a CTE query, and I manage to join the CTE when the data in CTE is match with another table.

For example, this is how my CTE query result looks like:

```
ID     NAME    REG      INV      CUS       BR
-----------------------------------------------
1     A0001   R0001    I0001    C0001     B0001
2     A0002   R0002    I0002    C0002     B0002
3     A0003   R0003    I0003    C0003     B0003
4     A0004   R0004    I0004    C0004     B0004
```

And this is the table I manage to join it to:

```
ID    NAME     CUS 
---------------------
1     TEST1   C0001
2     TEST2   C0002
3     TEST3   C0003
4     TEST4   C0004
```

And this is my code to select CTE query

```
;WITH BaseQuery AS 
(
    SELECT  
        Id, Name, Comment, 
        CONVERT(XML, '<root><item>' 
                + REPLACE(
                    REPLACE(
                        REPLACE(
                            REPLACE((SELECT Comment AS '*' FOR XML PATH('')), 
                            'Reg:', 
                            '</item><item type="Reg">'), 
                        'Inv:', 
                        '</item><item type="Inv">'), 
                    'Cus:', 
                    '</item><item type="Cus">'), 
                'Br:', 
                '</item><item type="Br">') + '</item></root>') CommentAsXml
    FROM    
        GenTransaction
), Query (
SELECT  
    Id, Name, Comment, 
    Reg = LTRIM(RTRIM(bq.CommentAsXml.value('(root/item[@type="Reg"])[1]', 'VARCHAR(11)'))),
    Inv = LTRIM(RTRIM(bq.CommentAsXml.value('(root/item[@type="Inv"])[1]', 'VARCHAR(11)'))),
    Cus = LTRIM(RTRIM(bq.CommentAsXml.value('(root/item[@type="Cus"])[1]', 'VARCHAR(11)'))),
    Br  = LTRIM(RTRIM(bq.CommentAsXml.value('(root/item[@type="Br"])[1]', 'VARCHAR(11)'))) 
FROM    
    BaseQuery bq
)
```

select ArCustomer.Name, Query.Cus 
from ArCustomer  left join Query 
on ArCustomer.Customer = Query.ArCustomer.Customer
order by ArCustomer.Name

Comment: You can use CTE result only once, so for using it in another join you have few options: 1. Join CTE result with another table in your first query. 2. Save CTE result in table variable and re-use it with another table. 3. Put first query of CTE result in another CTE and use second CTE result with another table

Comment: thanks, i have the problem in selecting the CTE query and do the compare with other

Comment: @tang: What issue do you have ? Are you trying to JOIN the results of CTE with another table ?

Comment: yes, i trying to join table based on CUS column (wich spllit from CTE query) with another table@BogdanSahlean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ 1 ] Using two CTEs (BaseQuery, Query and join between table and Query):

```
;WITH BaseQuery AS 
(
    SELECT  
        Id, Name, Comment, 
        CONVERT(XML, '<root><item>' 
                + REPLACE(
                    REPLACE(
                        REPLACE(
                            REPLACE((SELECT Comment AS '*' FOR XML PATH('')), 
                            'Reg:', 
                            '</item><item type="Reg">'), 
                        'Inv:', 
                        '</item><item type="Inv">'), 
                    'Cus:', 
                    '</item><item type="Cus">'), 
                'Br:', 
                '</item><item type="Br">') + '</item></root>') CommentAsXml
    FROM    
        GenTransaction
), Query (
SELECT  
    Id, Name, Comment, 
    Reg = LTRIM(RTRIM(bq.CommentAsXml.value('(root/item[@type="Reg"])[1]', 'VARCHAR(11)'))),
    Inv = LTRIM(RTRIM(bq.CommentAsXml.value('(root/item[@type="Inv"])[1]', 'VARCHAR(11)'))),
    Cus = LTRIM(RTRIM(bq.CommentAsXml.value('(root/item[@type="Cus"])[1]', 'VARCHAR(11)'))),
    Br  = LTRIM(RTRIM(bq.CommentAsXml.value('(root/item[@type="Br"])[1]', 'VARCHAR(11)'))) 
FROM    
    BaseQuery bq
)
SELECT ...
FROM Table1 t1 INNER/LEFT OUTER/... JOIN Query q ON ... join condition ... -- Query represents the second CTE
ORDER BY ...
```

[ 2 ] Second solution is based also on two CTEs (BaseQuery and Query) but instead of JOIN is using APPLY operator thus:

```
;WITH BaseQuery AS 
(
    SELECT  
        Id, Name, Comment, 
        CONVERT(XML, '<root><item>' 
                + REPLACE(
                    REPLACE(
                        REPLACE(
                            REPLACE((SELECT Comment AS '*' FOR XML PATH('')), 
                            'Reg:', 
                            '</item><item type="Reg">'), 
                        'Inv:', 
                        '</item><item type="Inv">'), 
                    'Cus:', 
                    '</item><item type="Cus">'), 
                'Br:', 
                '</item><item type="Br">') + '</item></root>') CommentAsXml
    FROM    
        GenTransaction
), Query (
SELECT  
    Id, Name, Comment, 
    Reg = LTRIM(RTRIM(bq.CommentAsXml.value('(root/item[@type="Reg"])[1]', 'VARCHAR(11)'))),
    Inv = LTRIM(RTRIM(bq.CommentAsXml.value('(root/item[@type="Inv"])[1]', 'VARCHAR(11)'))),
    Cus = LTRIM(RTRIM(bq.CommentAsXml.value('(root/item[@type="Cus"])[1]', 'VARCHAR(11)'))),
    Br  = LTRIM(RTRIM(bq.CommentAsXml.value('(root/item[@type="Br"])[1]', 'VARCHAR(11)'))) 
FROM    
    BaseQuery bq
)
SELECT ... t1.Col1 ... x.Col2 ...
FROM Table1 t1 
OUTER/CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT ...
    FROM Query q 
    WHERE ... join condition ... -- Query represents the second CTE
) x
ORDER BY ...
```

[ 3 ] Another solution is to insert those rows (extracted from Comment column) into a temp table (#Results) and then JOIN temp (#Results) table with another table (Table1):

```
;WITH BaseQuery AS 
(
    SELECT  
        Id, Name, Comment, 
        CONVERT(XML, '<root><item>' 
                + REPLACE(
                    REPLACE(
                        REPLACE(
                            REPLACE((SELECT Comment AS '*' FOR XML PATH('')), 
                            'Reg:', 
                            '</item><item type="Reg">'), 
                        'Inv:', 
                        '</item><item type="Inv">'), 
                    'Cus:', 
                    '</item><item type="Cus">'), 
                'Br:', 
                '</item><item type="Br">') + '</item></root>') CommentAsXml
    FROM    
        GenTransaction
)
SELECT  
    Id, Name, Comment, 
    Reg = LTRIM(RTRIM(bq.CommentAsXml.value('(root/item[@type="Reg"])[1]', 'VARCHAR(11)'))),
    Inv = LTRIM(RTRIM(bq.CommentAsXml.value('(root/item[@type="Inv"])[1]', 'VARCHAR(11)'))),
    Cus = LTRIM(RTRIM(bq.CommentAsXml.value('(root/item[@type="Cus"])[1]', 'VARCHAR(11)'))),
    Br  = LTRIM(RTRIM(bq.CommentAsXml.value('(root/item[@type="Br"])[1]', 'VARCHAR(11)'))) 
INTO #Results
FROM    
    BaseQuery bq; -- ORDER BY here should be used within final query

SELECT ...
FROM Table1 t1 INNER/LEFT OUTER/... JOIN #Results r ON ... join condition build using t1./r... ...
ORDER BY ...


Id, Name, Comment
```

Answer (score 2):

From documentation of [WITH common_table_expression (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql)

> Specifies a temporary named result set, known as a common table
>   expression (CTE). This is derived from a simple query and defined
>   within the execution scope of a **single SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, or
>   DELETE statement**.

Because CTE result scoped for only one statement you need to save result of `SELECT` query in table variable or create another CTE

With table variable

```
DECLARE @BaseData AS TABLE (
    Id INT,
    Name VARCHAR(50),
    Comment VARCHAR(500),
    Reg VARCHAR(11),
    Inv VARCHAR(11),
    Cus VARCHAR(11),
    Br VARCHAR(11)
)

;WITH BaseQuery AS 
(
    -- your CTE
)

INSERT INTO @BaseData 
SELECT Id, Name, Comment, 
    Reg = LTRIM(RTRIM(bq.CommentAsXml.value('(root/item[@type="Reg"])[1]','VARCHAR(11)'))),
    Inv = LTRIM(RTRIM(bq.CommentAsXml.value('(root/item[@type="Inv"])[1]','VARCHAR(11)'))),
    Cus = LTRIM(RTRIM(bq.CommentAsXml.value('(root/item[@type="Cus"])[1]','VARCHAR(11)'))),
    Br  = LTRIM(RTRIM(bq.CommentAsXml.value('(root/item[@type="Br"])[1]','VARCHAR(11)'))) 
FROM BaseQuery
ORDER BY Id, Name, Comment

-- Join it with another table
SELECT *
FROM AnotherTable at
INNER JOIN @BaseData bd ON bd.Id = at.SomeId
```

WITH another CTE

```
;WITH BaseQuery AS 
(
    -- your CTE
)
,
BaseResult AS 
(
    SELECT Id, Name, Comment, 
    Reg = LTRIM(RTRIM(bq.CommentAsXml.value('(root/item[@type="Reg"])[1]','VARCHAR(11)'))),
    Inv = LTRIM(RTRIM(bq.CommentAsXml.value('(root/item[@type="Inv"])[1]','VARCHAR(11)'))),
    Cus = LTRIM(RTRIM(bq.CommentAsXml.value('(root/item[@type="Cus"])[1]','VARCHAR(11)'))),
    Br  = LTRIM(RTRIM(bq.CommentAsXml.value('(root/item[@type="Br"])[1]','VARCHAR(11)'))) 
    FROM BaseQuery
)

-- Join  second result with another table
SELECT *
FROM AnotherTable at
INNER JOIN BaseResult br ON br.Id = at.SomeId
```

Comment: thanks, let say i nid to join the id , is generated by CTE query , how to apply the code?

Comment: my Inv, reg, cus table is split from Comment column, but i nid to use cus table as the id to join with other table variable

Comment: There you find information for joining two tables: [Using Joins](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191472(v=sql.105).aspx). Consider CTE as a table when joining it.

Comment: if i join the table like normal query it get the error, i cant get the data that split from original column